# 0 and 1 on diagram ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dummy-variable

My data is

```
   black wage
1      0  769
2      0  808
3      0  825
4      0  650
5      0  562
6      1 1400
7      0  600
8      0 1081
9      0 1154
10     0 1000
```

my code is

```
b <- lm(wage~black, y)

ggplot(b, aes(black, wage)) + 
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red", se = F) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = '黑人', y = '薪水') +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(text = element_text(family='黑體-繁 中黑'),
        plot.title = element_text(size = rel(2.5), face = 'bold', hjust = 0.5),
        axis.title = element_text(size = rel(1.5), face = 'bold'),
        axis.text = element_text(size = rel(2), face = 'bold', colour = 'Black'),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(colour = NA))
```

regression plot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO0nZ.png

I want my diagram to only have 0 and 1 on the x-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By `scale_x_continuous`,

```
ggplot(b, aes(black, wage)) + 
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red", se = F) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = '黑人', y = '薪水') +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(text = element_text(family='黑體-繁 中黑'),
        plot.title = element_text(size = rel(2.5), face = 'bold', hjust = 0.5),
        axis.title = element_text(size = rel(1.5), face = 'bold'),
        axis.text = element_text(size = rel(2), face = 'bold', colour = 'Black'),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(colour = NA)) +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1, by = 1),"黑人")
```

[image]